# Is there an existing CodeIgniter helper/library that uses PHP DateTime class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Does anyone know of an existing CodeIgniter (CI 2.0) Helper (or Library) that I can use to help with date and time formatting for views? Maybe something that uses the PHP5 DateTime class?

Most of our data is in the typical GMT/UTC format within a MySQL database. We now need to set a User's timezone (part of our admin/auth/acl) and then display everything by their timezone setting. I assume this would be easy to do with a CI helper or perhaps a library. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

PHP's [DateTime Classes and functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) are **fully** available in CodeIgniter.  No Library/Helper required...

Answer (score 1):

That kind of things is so specific that you'll have to make it yourself.
See [creating CI libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) and [helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

Comment: I'm sure it's been done a couple hundred times before. I see the Date helper for CI; looks interesting. I'm now wondering if using the CI Date help is the better approach, rather than using the PHP5 DateTime classes?

Answer (score 1):

I was actually facing the same problem with a project about a year ago, and I was working on CI too. I just ended up using php's DateTime and DateTimezone stuff. It was tricky at first, but a little bit of googling helped. Perhaps this would help?
http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/03/21/handling-timezone-conversion-with-php-datetime/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use CI but I see it has a filter system. Implement a filter that issues a SET TIME_ZONE query on the DB connection before your controllers run. You'll get all the dates/times out of the database in the user's local time zone without having to make any changes to any controller, view or database code.